# Passing method, html/php

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

If i have 3 checkboxes that you can check for the transport available: Taxi, Train, Bus.. how should i pass them in a nice way? Cant you like pass a array with Transport = bus, train (those you checked), or maybe you have to send them seperatly one variable at a time, because it is inside a form (and already are a array all of it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about sending the data from the client to the server. If so, you can give the checkboxes the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="Taxi"> Taxi <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="Train"> Train <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="Bus"> Bus <br />
```

When you sent the form, the data will be available as array in `$_POST['transport']` (or `$_GET`, depending on which methods you use). The `[]` in the input field name will make PHP parse the data as array.

More information in [*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

---

**Some more explanation:**

Without the brackets (i.e. `[]`), the resulting query string would look like this (assuming Taxi and Train are selected):

```
transport=Taxi&transport=Train
```

PHP, in contrast to other languages, will only consider the last value for the same key. In order to make PHP treat values with  the same key as array, you have to append `[]` to the name.

Comment: Thank you, what is this method called? array form?

Comment: @Karem: It does not have a name. It's how to make PHP recognize an array.

Answer (score 0):

All input fields will be passed as part of your $_POST or $_GET arrays, based on the method type of your form submission.  Checkboxes are passed as name=on or name= whether the checkboxes are selected or not. Depending on how you're processing the submitted form data there are different ways to work with the values.  I hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="bus" />
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="train" />
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="taxi" />
```

The values will be passed as an array accessible with $_POST['transport']. If the user checks the first and the last checkboxes $_POST['transport'] will contain two strings: `0 => "bus", 1 => "taxi"`.

Also see http://jetlogs.org/2007/07/19/passing-input-arrays-in-php/.